# Optional tensors in PyTorch c++ extension

Tags: c++, pytorch, torch

I'm writing  a C++ extension for pytorch, and using the c++ api to do so. To my `forward` function, I need to pass an optional tensor. Inside the function, I want to do different things based on whether this optional parameter was passed or not. In general, we use NULL for optional pointer arguments in C++ and check inside the function if the pointer is NULL or not. I don't know how to do this for the `at::Tensor` type of Torch's c++ api.

```
void xyz_forward(
    const at::Tensor xyz1, 
    const at::Tensor xyz2, 
    const at::Tensor optional_constraints = something)
{
     if(optional_constraints){
        //do something
     }else{
        //do something else
     }
}
```

Note that, I can't do `const at::Tensor optional_constraints = at::ones` or something, because that parameter can take any real value and can be of varying size/shape. I can't assign it a numerical value as an optional argument. Is there a `NULL` equivalent for this?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but can't you check if `optional_constraints == nullptr`?

Comment: @Coolness Unfortunately `optional_constrains` is not pointer.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility could be to use [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) as `std::optional<at::Tensor> optional_constraints = std::nullopt`. It is contextually convertible to `bool`, so you can check it with `if (optional_constraints)`. Use the `.value()` method to get the tensor if you pass one, otherwise the default value will be `std::nullopt`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't find anything similar to eg. OpenCV `noArray()` (which is basically used for passing optinal matrixes, like masks) in the [API](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/notes/tensor_creation.html), I would suggest you using the overloaded function for such purpose

```
void xyz_forward(
    const at::Tensor xyz1, 
    const at::Tensor xyz2)
{
     // optional tensor wasnt passed
}
```

---

```
void xyz_forward(
    const at::Tensor xyz1, 
    const at::Tensor xyz2, 
    const at::Tensor optional_constraints)
{
     // optional tensor passed
}
```